# Django Rest Framework different format response format for same URL and HTTP method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I working on an application with uses Django Rest Framework to handle queries and I use **django-rest-framework-datatables** plugin to help me handle pagination to datatables.

Works fine, but when I request for a single register it keeps bringing me a json format for datatables, like this:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "University of Passo Fundo",
        "country": "Brazil"
    }]
}
```

This is not a big issue, but I would prefer to receive just the result field. How can I defined two different response format for a same URL and same method, just checking request parameters in django rest framework?

Follow my code:

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'institution', InstitutionViewSet, base_name='Institution')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),

    # api
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),

    # views
    url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'institution/', Institution.as_view(), name='institution'),
]
```

**serializer.py**

```
class InstitutionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Institution
        fields = '__all__'
        datatables_always_serialize = ('id', 'name', 'country')
```

**models.py**

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=255, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(db_column='country', max_length=255, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Institution'
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'Institutions'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Institutions'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class InstitutionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = InstitutionSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'type' in self.request.GET and self.request.GET['type'] == 'edit':
            return Institution.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET['id'])
        return Institution.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that's the way Django render response for pagination.
So you can see the next or previous list of items based on the page.

And second you should override the list view of Django to be like this:

```
class InstituttionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = InstitutionSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In here, we are overriding the list method which is responsible to render a list of items API. So it will first get all items in `queryset`, then pass it to serializer to write it to a specific format, and at last return that lists in json for a response.

Also, remember I also set `pagination_class=None` So Django will not use pagination for APIs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think You shouldn't override `get_queryset` view's method, this should solve your problem. The [drf views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) handle default param by default via `retrieve` method. You can use your own [pagination class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) to edit response schema.

Comment: retrieve method is not responsible to return the list of items. He should override the `list` method of ModelViewSet.

Comment: He wrote about one element I think - "I request for a single register it keeps bringing me a json format for datatables"

Comment: As he mentioned datatables is for rendering list of items. And retrieve should get a pk element from Url to path to views.py

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method, [get_serializer_class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) and use two different serializer depend of request parameter.